# How do I know when a different screensaver has been selected in the display properties dialog?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, screensaver

Ok so Google is not my friend tonight...

I have a screen saver, [CC.Votd (Full source on Codeplex)](http://ccvotd.codeplex.com/), and I've just started to implement the preview mode (/p argument) which is working ok. When it's in preview mode I make my form a child to the little computer monitor window and it draws in there.

This works fine and my application exits if the display properties dialog goes away.

The issue is that if I select my screen saver from the list and then select a different screen saver mine continues to run and draws over the newly selected screen saver's preview.

So how do I know when a different screen saver is selected and mine should close?

---

**Edit:** For Anon, here's the code I'm using to make my form a child of the preview window:

P/invokes:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, out Rectangle lpRect);
```

The code:

```
SetParent(Handle, _PreviewHandle);
SetWindowLong(Handle, -16, new IntPtr(GetWindowLong(Handle, -16) | 0x40000000));

Rectangle parentRectangle;
GetClientRect(_PreviewHandle, out parentRectangle);
Size = parentRectangle.Size;

Location = new Point(0, 0);
```

Complete form code: http://ccvotd.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/40085#862458

---

Forgot to mention that I tried using `IsWindowVisible()` and that didn't work since the preview window is still visible and has the same handle as when my screen saver was selected.

**Edit:** Before I added the `SetParent()` and associated calls my application would continue to run after the display dialog was closed so I think that part is working and something different happens when the user selects a different screen saver.

---

As John K suggested I've been looking at my form with Spy++. I never see the WS_CHILD style applied. However all my debugging suggests it should be. I modified the code to:

```
long style = GetWindowLong(Handle, -16);
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Original Style: " + style);
style &= ~0x800000000;
style |= 0x40000000;
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Adjusted Style: " + style);

SetWindowLong(Handle, -16, new IntPtr(style));
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("After Set Style: " + GetWindowLong(Handle, -16));
SetParent(Handle, _PreviewHandle);
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("After Set Parent: " + GetWindowLong(Handle, -16));
```

And the style is the same on the last three traces, two of which should be getting the value from the form itself. Going to research my native API calls and clean up their declarations to see what I can figure out.

Thanks for all the help so far!

---

**Solution:** The problem ended up being that I was setting several properties of the form that resulted in the underlying .NET control overwriting my new styles. So changing:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

Capture = true;

if (!_IsPreview)
{
    // Removed ...
}
else
{
    SetWindowLong(Handle, -16, new IntPtr(GetWindowLong(Handle, -16) | 0x40000000));
    SetParent(Handle, _PreviewHandle);

    Rectangle parentRectangle;
    GetClientRect(_PreviewHandle, out parentRectangle);
    Size = parentRectangle.Size;

    Location = new Point(0, 0);
}

ShowInTaskbar = false;
DoubleBuffered = true;
BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

To:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
Capture = true;
DoubleBuffered = true;
ShowInTaskbar = false;

if (!_IsPreview)
{
    // Removed ...
}
else
{
    SetWindowLong(Handle, -16, new IntPtr(GetWindowLong(Handle, -16) | 0x40000000));
    SetParent(Handle, _PreviewHandle);

    Rectangle parentRectangle;
    GetClientRect(_PreviewHandle, out parentRectangle);
    Size = parentRectangle.Size;

    Location = new Point(0, 0);
}
```

Fixed the problem. Simple mistake :-)

---

The correct way to solve it... override CreateParams:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;

        if (!DesignMode && _IsPreview)
        {
            createParams.Style |= 0x40000000;
        }

        return createParams;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to create the preview window as a child of the passed-in HWND?

Comment: @Anon: Sure thing, I found it from an example and haven't really examined it much beyond the fact it seems to be working for me :-)

Comment: The screensaver dialogue destroys the preview window when the user switches screensavers - do you listen for this?

Comment: @Anon: No I don't but if this was the case wouldn't that result in the preview window getting a new handle and thus causing my drawing to the old handle to fail, or at least not draw over the newly selected screen saver? Or since I was checking IsWindowVisible() with the old handle shouldn't that return false after the original window is destroyed?

Comment: Your form should be getting destroyed when the user switches because it's a child of the preview window.  I think either your form doesn't have the WS_CHILD style or SetParent isn't working.

Comment: @John: I agree but since my application exits when the user clicks Ok/Cancel in the display dialog I can't explain it. Obviously when the display dialog is closed the preview window is destroyed. So when the user switches screen savers I think something different is happening.

Comment: You can use Spy++ to verify parentage and WS_CHILD style. Other than that I would say add an OnMessage override to your form and see what messages you are getting.

Comment: @John: Good call. It doesn't have the WS_CHILD style and has an Owner but not a Parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once apon a time trying to change the WS_CHILD style of a window after it was already created would just quietly fail.  I think they changed that in current versions of windows, but to be sure, you should really be creating your preview form as a child window from the start.

I have a hunch that your window isn't ending up a child window of the preview.
you could try this.

```
SetParent(Handle, _PreviewHandle);
SetWindowLong(Handle, -16, new IntPtr(GetWindowLong(Handle, -16) | 0x40000000));
SetParent(Handle, _PreviewHandle);
```

SetParent *after* you change your window style to WS_CHILD.

Also, you may not have the WS_POPUP style on  your form, but if you do, you want to remove it.

```
int style = GetWindowLong(Handle, -16);
style &= ~0x800000000;
style |= 0x40000000;
SetWindowLong(Handle, -16, new IntPtr(style));
```

What's happening here is that SetParent sets the parent of child windows, but it sets the *owner* of WS_POPUP and WS_OVERLAPPED windows.